# About $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ and its generators

Tags: group-theory, notation, commutator, lie-algebra

I am taking a class of SUSY at my university and the teacher was explaining $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ has generators $\sigma_{ab}$, for $a<b$, on the $\rho_0(N)$ representation, with:

\begin{align*}
\sigma_{ab}\equiv -\frac{1}{4}(\sigma_a\overline{\sigma_b}-\sigma_b\overline{\sigma_a})
\end{align*}

Where $\overline{\sigma}=\epsilon\sigma^T\epsilon^{-1}$. What is $\epsilon$ in this case?

The sigma is referring to the Pauli matrices, and I wanted to calculate the commutatiors for $[\sigma_{ab},\sigma_{bc}]$, $[\overline{\sigma_{ab}},\overline{\sigma_{cd}}]$ and $[\overline{\sigma_{ab}},\sigma_{cd}]$. I know how to calculate them, the problem is to get the overlined sigmas because of the $\epsilon$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is hard to understand what the lecturere is getting at from what you ask. The generators of ${\mathfrak sl}(2 {\mathbb C})$ are just the three Pauli sigma's but with complex coefficients allowed.  I have never heard of a $\rho_0(N)$ representation either. What is it?